# What is the Limit

Tags: calculus

$$lim(x→0) ⁡[sinx/x]$$ 
Where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function. We know that when $x$ is very small,  $sinx<x$ so for $lim$ $x→ 0+$  $ sin$x$/x$ is less than $1$. Therefore $$lim(x→0) ⁡[sinx/x] = 0$$
Now What is the value of $$lim( x→0) \ ⁡sin[x]/[x]$$  I  know that when $lim$ $x→ 0-$ value is $sin(-1)/(-1)$ but when $lim$ $x→ 0+$ it is in $ 0/0$ form. So Does RHL exists? Or can we use L'Hospitals rule in finding above limits and how?

Comment: Your function is not defined on $[0,1[$, so its limit in $0^+$ is undefined

Comment: "Greatest integer" might mislead. "Greatest integer not greater than x" is more real

Comment: I thought that this limit dne but i found similar  limit to be 0 in books and actual problem was $$lim(x→0) (⁡[x]^2+sin[x])/[x]$$ 
so i had the doubt in $$lim( x→0) \ ⁡sin[x]/[x]$$   portion